# Dual-Channel Recording Using Plivo?

Tags: audio, split, mono, plivo

Plivo has mentioned on their Voice SDK features that Plivo supports Dual-channel call recording
and Recordings are dual-channel by default and stored encrypted. However I do not see where to get two different audio urls from the call recording.

Does anyone has idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Plivo makes mono recordings of conference calls and stereo recordings of regular calls. Having said that, for dual-channel recording(stereo) Plivo provides the audio of both the participants in separate channels.

You can listen to the audio of:

- participant1 channel (the left speaker when played with stereo speakers).
- participant2 channel (the right speaker when played with stereo speakers).

Hope this is helpful, please refer to our [Record Calls guide](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/use-cases/record-calls/python/) for more details about the recording feature. Thanks!

Comment: I have also read it on Plivo documents, but there is no where they have written about how to retrieve audios of a separate channel. When i retrieve audio it just gives a single url which plays speaker 1 and speaker 2 voice together

Comment: basically i want to Splitting stereo audio to mono

Comment: you should be able to split it using Audacity or some other audio editing tool. Refer: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/splitting_and_joining_stereo_tracks.html

Comment: So plivo does not provide splited audio files, right?

Comment: unfortunately, Plivo doesn't provide split audio files at the moment. However, you can achieve this using the [Multiparty Call feature](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/api/multiparty-call/) that enables to manage the [recording at a participant level](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/api/multiparty-call/participants/participant-level-recording#start-recording). You can also refer to the details in the detailed [use case guide](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/use-cases/supervisor-coaching/python). Thanks!